# How to get a response using RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, message-queue

Two microservices (CustomerService, OrderService) are communicating with each other using rabbitMQ. However, I want to get a response from the OrderService on whether the request has been successful or got any errors.

Is it possible to change **`void consumerpublic()`** to ResponseEntity to get the statusCode or make the OrderService call the CustomerService back?

***Controller class***

```
   @PostMapping("/addItems")
   public ResponseEntity <String> addItems(@Valid @RequestBody Item item ){
     Message result = producer.sendMessage(item);
    
     return ResponseEntity.ok("message sent to RabbitMQ ..." + item);
   }
```

***RabbitMQProducer.java***

```
  private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

  public void sendMessage(Item item){
    rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(exchange,routingKey, item);
    log.info(String.format("Message sent -> %s", item.toString()));
  }
```

***RabbitMQConsumer.java***

```
 @RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbitmq.queue.name}")
public void consumerpublic(Item item){
    System.out.println(Item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Messaging Queues are Asynchronous in Nature that means the Response will be Asynchronous too.

What I am trying to say is as the flow between the two microservices is Asynchronous there needs to be some Identifier present at both ends using which you can relate which Order (Order Id) is being related to Which Customer(Customer Id) and What Items(Items Id) it Have.

Customer(Customer Id) will have a list of Orders (Order Id)

The Simplest thing would be to Use a OrderIdentifier while sending and after it is successful update it in DB with the Status and while fetching the Customer Orders data from UI/API you can get the Status Back.